# How do I get Windows XP to display a boot menu at all?

Tags: boot

When I started up my Dell Dimension 4500 with Windows XP again after I installed Ubuntu, I don't even get a boot menu to choose.  How do I make one appear?

Answer (score 0):

what you exactly mean ??? if you have booted xp, then
you are in the area of xp.

when you want to install a boot-menu after installation of ubuntu,
you need to boot into ubuntu from beginning.
then open terminal in ubuntu:
assumed you have no cd-drive then harddisk is /dev/sda
command is simply:
grub-install /dev/sda
(wait until it is finish)
then type command:
update-grub

in the end you have a grub-boot-menu installed on your harddisk.
assumed you dont know which "logical name" your harddisk has, you can find it out
with command
sudo lshw -class disk
(conditioned you have made a partition-table in ubuntu before installing ubuntu).
cheers.